# Angular2 input text value is not showing although its model contain the value

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-ngmodel

I got annoying situation with my Angular2 application, I have a table with several rows, each row contain columns with 2 way binding using [(ngModel)].
I have 2 buttons of Add and Delete and they push/splice the list of values that is used for the table.

When pushing a new item to the list or splice (delete) item from the list - the table is well updated.

The only bug is when I delete a row (item) from the list and then add a new item, one row from the table is then displayed with empty values somehow, when I checked the html source in Chrome's developer tool I saw that the model of the row is containing the correct value, so it is only a problem on display.
How can it be?

Comment: Please show your code. If possible, try to reproduce the issue in [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/tpl:AvJOMERrnz94ekVua0u5)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to lack of display in Angular2 when delete element inside a loop, I solved it by changing delete action to do: clear the list items and create the same elements excluding the element that should be deleted.

Comment: can you further explain this using an example

Comment: You should use immutable objects when display is based on list.push (if it is possible use immutable always) since the strategy of display changes is probably slow.
check this:

https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/change-detection/enforcing_immutability.html